# Android: Enabling/disabling buttons

Tags: java, android, button

I was wondering how to enable a button when a user meets a certain criteria (that is, height and width greater than 1 for a puzzle board's dimensions) AFTER setting it to false...

Because, based on my following code, the button remains disabled in the virtual emulator:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

// Class used to retrieve user-input values in order to create the puzzle board based on its
// dimensions as shown in the SecondActivity class.
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// Initializes fields.
    private EditText etHeight, etWidth;
    private int height, width;
    private Button instructions, play;

    // Main method.
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Instantiates the following variables by reference ID.
        instructions = (Button)findViewById(R.id.instructionsButton);
        play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        play.setEnabled(false);

        instructions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, PopUpActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Instantiates the components of a dimension with Android's interfaces.
                etHeight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterHeight);
                String ht = etHeight.getText().toString();

                // Convert to other data types accordingly.
                height = Integer.parseInt(ht);

                etWidth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterWidth);
                String wh = etWidth.getText().toString();
                width = Integer.parseInt(wh);

                if (height > 1 && width > 1) {
                    play.setEnabled(true);
                }

                Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                // Compile data to the Bundle interface.
                i.putExtra("height", height);
                i.putExtra("width", width);
                //v.setEnabled(true);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You already disable your button here: `play.setEnabled(false);` What is your question?

Comment: You already did it, just need to validate the user input for the puzzle size... a spinner or text view with regex???

Comment: @dpark14 Do you want to enable Play button after a user fill width and height edittexts?

Comment: Yes, enable it. Sorry for not being clear; I was in a rush

Comment: you are starting a new activity whether the height/width is bigger than 1 or not - so you can't use the enabled button anyway... what's the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the set enabled to true in a   onTextChanged method of the edit text when the text meets certain criteria.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found the TextWatcher interface definitely applicable in my program.